# pg_switch_wal In Point In Time Recovery PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-11

I was following [this](https://www.scalingpostgres.com/tutorials/postgresql-backup-point-in-time-recovery/) tutorial about point in time recovery in postgres and come up with the following questions. Can anybody help me.

- Is it necessary to use `pg_basebackup` every time I want to back up the database or the postgres backs up the database and stores somewhere considering its configurations?
- What does the `psql -c "select pg_switch_wal();"`do? and is it necessary to run every time I want to back up the database?

I use postgres 11 on ubuntu 18.04.3 if that helps.

**EDIT**

Let me be more specific in my question. As I've understood by searching on the internet, we should have two files to back up the database: one base which contains the general files such as table attributes and a WAL file which contain the log files showing instances in the database. And I have seen that `pg_basebackup` backs up whole database cluster not only WAL files, so there should be a function which only backs up WAL files.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, you can run "pg_basebackup" just once (or once per major version upgrade) but then it will take longer and longer to do a restore, as it has to run through all the accumulated WAL since that backup.  So it usually makes sense to do a new pg_basebackup periodically.

"The database" won't do it for you.  There are a variety of backup tools out there that probably will (pg_barman, pgbackrest, pg_probackup, etc.).  But you didn't mention using any of them.

pg_switch_wal() is not necessary as pg_basebackup does it for you.

pg_basebackup will archive the wal files if you set it to, but will only do so for WAL files which are generated during the duration of the base backup itself.  This is suitable for a snapshot backup, but not for PITR.  In other words, it will let you restore to the exact moment the backup command finished, but is not enough to let you restore to some point after that time. To backup WAL files at other times, you need to set the "archive_command" setting to something that will copy the files for you.  (Also, if you have a valid "archive_command" in place **before you start** the basebackup, then the basebackup itself doesn't really need to backup the WAL in the first place.  Then the base backup will not be self contained, you will have to pair it with the WAL archive in order to restore.)

The tutorial you refer to shows a setting for "archive_command".  However, the setting it shows is not bullet-proof.  As [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html) say, "this is an example, not a recommendation".  It has two main problems.  Once is that it does not fsync the copy before declaring success.  That means the system can remove/recycle the WAL file from pg_wal, before the copy of it has been flushed to the disk drive; and so a crash at the wrong time can leave you with zero valid copies.  The other problem is that it seems to be copying the file locally.  That means that if your computer is destroyed, you will lose your backup at the same time as you lose your master copy.  (It is possible that it is not copying locally, because /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive might be a network mounted file-system; but if so then that exacerbates the fsync problem, how do you know the copy on the remote file system is truly safe?)

If you don't want to use "archive_command", then another tool is "pg_receivewal".  You would run this on another server, and it will connect to your Postgresql instance and "pull" the wal files, rather than the "push" that "archive_command" does.

Yet another option is to set up a streaming standby on another server, set "archive_mode" to "always", and then have "archive_command" run on the standby, rather than on the master, to save your WAL files.

Comment: thanks for reply, Let me be more specific in question, Is ```pg_basebackup``` backs up all the data or just the base files? If ```pg_basebackup``` backs up only base or backs up data that are not necessary ( I mean that as its name suggests that this tool backs up the base files), So how could I backup only wal files so that my back up would have much less volume?

Comment: If you want to expand on your question could you put the extra detail in the question (edit) and then let the person who answered know by putting @ in front of their handle (no space). p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: The behavior of pg_basebackup has changed from version to version.  In 11, it will automatically backup the wal files it needs in order to make a self contained base backup, unless you go out of your way to tell it not to.  Of course it will not back up **future** wal files.  That is what "archive_command" is for.

Comment: Is there a way to back up only wal files so that the backup process finishes fast? Is it applicable that once we back up base files and then only back up wal files?@jjanes

Comment: If you only have WAL files, then you can't restore.  You need at least one base backup.  Again, backing up only WAL files is what archive_command is for.  There is no "mode" of pg_basebackup that tells it not to do a base backup.  My screwdriver does not have a setting for baking bread.

Comment: I'm sorry if these comments get too long, I'm almost new to database world, but let me clear my question Is there a tool other than ```pg_basebackup``` and in general to archive only WAL files?@jjanes

Answer (score 2):

`pg_basebackup` creates a complete copy of the database. You need transaction log (WAL) archives to make the backup consistent during restore and to continue replaying all thr data modifications until the point to which you want to recover.

You have to schedule regular base backups as starting points for recovery, otherwise recovery will take too long.

In the event of an outage, you can recover the database using a base backup and WAL archives. What you cannot recover are the last data modifications that are not archived yet, because they are in the currently active WAL file. I guess the page you were reading uses `pg_switch_wal()` to switch to a new WAL file and archive the current one so that they can recover the last fee transactions.

Normally, if you cannot lose any data even in the event of a catastrophe, you archive WAL with `pg_receivewal` rather than with `archive_command`.

Comment: Could you explain the second paragraph and the fourth one a bit more?

Comment: Second paragraph: you can keep replaying transaction logs, but if you replay too many, it will take too long. So you perform regular backups to keep recovery time moderate. Fourth paragraph: That builds on the third one. It mentions `pg_receivewal` as a tool to overcome the limitation described in the third paragraph. Read the documentation for more about `pg_receivewal`.

Comment: What if I know that after backup with `pg_basebackup` there were not any transactions. Is it possible to PITR database if I have only this base backup? Without none additional WAL files I get `XX000: recovery ended before configured recovery target was reached`, though without RECOVERY_TARGET_TIME this backup restored without any problem. Base backup was done with `wal-g push-backup`.

Comment: @EugenKonkov That depends how you set the `-X` option of `pg_basebackup`. You will need WAL to recover a base backup, but sometimes it is included in the backup.

Comment: What if I just want to restore base backup with PITR without WAL files? This is just test. I insert few records into database, then I did basebackup (wal-g seems do that with low level API pg_bakup_start/stop). I did not find any information that it is not possible to restore this backup with RECOVERTY_TARGET_TIME exactly when this backup was finished. On v11 this restore woks fine, on v15 fails.I found that this message was implemented in PGv13.In my logs I can see that consistent recovery point was reached, but then I got XX000.So why I get this errors without WAL if desired PIT was reached?

Comment: @EugenKonkov That was a bug that was fixed in v13, but not backpatched (see [the commit message](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=dc788668bb269b10a108e87d14fefd1b9301b793)). You should set `recovery_target = immediate`.